# Node.js child_process module with git command

Tags: node.js, child-process

First, Please understand that it's not smooth because I use a translator.

I want to create an API server using the child_process module in node.js to send git command.
ex) git clone ..., git pull, git push , ...

And i succeeded!

But there's a big problem here. ;(

```
execSync(cmd, {stdio: 'inherit', cwd: cwd});
```

This is my code.

'npm start' And use this API.

Logs are displayed in the cmd window.

It is displayed in the log like this, but I can't allocate it as a variable in my node code. Like stdout, stderr.

If you don't use '{stdio: 'inherit'}' this option, you're successfully assigned to the variable.

But I want to show the log of the server and assign it to the variables.

How can we catch two rabbits?

Comment: This isn't specific to Git: you'll find this applies to all child processes. (I don't do enough npm / node.js to know what you should use here though.)

Answer (score 0):

This would print the log (stdout), and the log is assigned to data.

```
const childProcess = require("child_process");
const git = childProcess.exec("git pull");

git.stdout.on("data", data => {
   console.log(`Git replied: ${data}`);
});
// Git replied: Already up to date.
```